# Desktop notification does not appear when an email is configured to be rooted to a folder

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

I use Microsoft Office 365 Outlook Web. I configured my Outlook Web to show desktop notifications.

When I do not apply a rule to an email address then I successfully receive desktop notifications, but when I apply a rule to an email address so that emails from this address are sent to a folder, then the notification does not appear!

How to fix that?